# Portable LG Ultrafine but 13-15"

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, usb-c

I'll show you my setup and what I'm trying to solve. This is for health reasons.

I work at a **co-working space**. I have to crouch over my laptop 6-7 hours per day.  **I get a bad back.**

I would like find a **portable usb-c powered monitor** that has an **adjustable stand** like the LG Ultrafine, also it needs to be a decent res, at least 4k would be nice. That way I can achieve eye-line viewing and still use the MacBook trackpad and keyboard. The perfect portable setup.

**Does this even exist?**

[image]